# Writing Behaviour (Python 2.7.11)

Tags: python, io

I have encountered a behaviour I do not know enough about to Google a solution, so please forgive me if this is some fundamental/ simple thing.

I write scripts typically at home on my Mac (El Capitan), do some minimal testing, then further test and tweak the script at work on a Windows machine (Windows 7).

In the proceeding pieces of code I use a function entitled "re_write" which is:

```
folder = "{}/Records/".format("/".join(os.getcwd().split("/")))

def re_write(file):
    return open(folder + file, "wb+")
```

Here is my module that initially writes to the file:

```
history = supp.re_write("Agent.txt")
history.write("{}{}".format("Verified: ", 
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))

exit()
```

This works as expected and prints:

```
Verified: 2016-02-10 08:15:25
```

However, if I run the following:

```
history = supp.re_write("Agent.txt")
history.write("{}{}".format("Verified: ",
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))

this = history.read().split("\n")[0].split(": ")
exit()
```

The following (or similar) is written to the file:

```
Verified: 2016-02-10 08:15:25ÅþÃ±¦†“VYÇC7] IiìCá¼G+»{’îÀ,[WÝŸKù…ºñ¶wdx^0øN»!Ó¿B®_7Ä5$Ÿ"=ÀÆ×ÐÁ³¢FŽQq±)S&Â,¾™{æ?½A#?åHÏýÖ£¨öô¿ƒ£F·Ïÿ  `$L‘ø°?HG|=g—Ðø!OvëZWCr9J×½¦šª¢óÿ^p½3w½`ñ,…FJÑph°öçkDæó’=ÞžˆÁ°¦é,Ì9¡MÈ+ú8ÁãcòcÛÞ?v¦
```

Though this only occurs on Windows, with my Mac not appending any visible superfluous sugar honey iced tea.

Basically, I am unsure as to what I should be looking for to discover or understand why reading a file on Windows would alter it upon it being read. I have tried encoding the string before writing though it seemingly achieved nothing. Where am I failing?

Thank you.

Comment: first line, red flag: Always use `os.path.join` instead of rolling your own folder path formatting. **Specially** if you aim to be multiplatform.

Comment: Why do you open the file in "binary" mode? Have you checked the encoding first? Are you sure you want to handle yourself the responsibility of being consistent with encodings? I would use text-mode and rely on Python doing a good job. If you are using Python 2.7, `from __future__ import unicode_literals` will do no harm --and probably a good idea, just in case.

Comment: After performing a `write`, if you want to read what you have just written, you need to perform some kind of `seek`. Otherwise, you will be reading whatever comes after the end of file --which may be garbage, OS-dependent, or some undefined behaviour. In any case: it does not seem to be what you want to read.

Comment: Lastly: `exit` should perform a clean exit and close the file handlers. However, it is always advisable to explicitly close the file before exiting. The `with supp.re_write("Agent.txt") as history:` pattern is a good idea to avoid the `.close()`, but you can choose whatever suits your script.

Comment: @MariusSiuram

1. I had not looked into the os.path.join method previously, though it reads like I should have.

2. Opening/ Reading/ Writing in text-only mode did not change the appended random characters. Though I cannot justify why I am using it... it is the first and only time I have. The change happened sometime after midnight of a long day... maybe I read something somewhere that made sense at the time...

Comment: 3. I had included history.seek(0) previously, and replaced it with the "exit()" when I was attempting to diagnose where the random characters were being added and forgot to put it back
4. I typically close all the files I open, though this extract is only a third of the full function it is a part of.

Thank you so much for your quick and knowledgeable replies.

Comment: Good to see that you had already done most of my suggestions. I am sorry, but I don't have any Windows machine, so I am unable to reproduce your problem :( good luck!

Comment: It is strange, I am unable to reproduce my problem using the same methods anywhere else in my script. However, I have bypassed the issue by simply not reading the file during this particular method. I may be overlooking something but it seems as though simply reading the file was appending the erroneous characters-- one for Mulder. Anyway, thanks again.